# Como "compartilhar" uma request entre as threads?

Tags: java, spring

Estou com um "problema" no sistema em que estou mexendo, é uma api em Java.

Há pouco tempo, começaram a implantar filtros a partir dos parâmetros das requisições. Para toda requisição, ele tem um `preHandle` que filtra essa requisição e grava uma `request`, até aí tudo certo. Depois disso, ele redireciona para o metódo mapeado que ele deve acessar, por exemplo:

**ClientAction**

```
@PostMapping("/rota/{param1}/{param2}/{param3}")
public void process(@PathVariable String param1, @PathVariable String param2, @PathVariable String param3) {
    List<Clients> clients = clientService.getClients();

    processService.process();

    ...
}
```

Com isso, ele executa um método que retorna todos os clientes, mas nesse método existe um filtro de requisição, caso tenha uma requisição, ele retorna ela para ser utilizada, caso ao contrário retorna nulo:

**ClientService**

```
public List<Clients> getClients() {
    HttpServletRequest request = SecurityService.getRequest();

    if (request != null) {
        .
        .
        .
        return clients;
    }
    return null;
}
```

**SecurityService**

```
public static HttpServletRequest getRequest() {
    HttpServletRequest request = null;
    RequestAttributes requestAttributes = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
    if (requestAttributes != null && requestAttributes instanceof ServletRequestAttributes) {
        request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) requestAttributes).getRequest();
    }
    return request;
}
```

Nessa primeira parte, ele retorna a lista de todos os clientes normalmente.

Após isso, ele executa o `processService.process()`, como exemplo abaixo:

**ProcessService**

```
public void process() {
    List<Clients> clients = clientService.getClients();
}
```

Aí que está o "problema", nesse método que é chamado, ele não consegue obter a lista de clientes, pois a `request` returna nula.

Tentei pesquisar, mas não obtive um resultado, encontrei algo que a requisição dessa forma, ela não consegue ser compartilhada entre as `threads` executadas, por isso não consegue retornar o valor.

Sei que uma solução, seria executar no primeiro método e passar a lista de clientes para os métodos abaixo, mas quero encontrar algo que eu possa "compartilhar" e executar nos métodos chamados, pois é um método grande, com várias lógicas e diferentes processos. Além disso, ter a possibilidade de poder chamar esse método de obter clientes, de qualquer lugar do sistema, sem ter que executar no método em que chega a requisição.

Se esse é o "problema", existe alguma forma de "compartilhar" isso entre as `threads`?

Se esse não é o "problema", por que isso ocorre ?

Answer (score 0):

Uma thread não consegue ter acesso a dados de outra thread devido à cada thread possuir seu próprio contexto individual.

Existem várias razões para isso acontecer:

1. Manter o isolamento entre as threads, evitando *leaking* de informações desnecessárias para threads que não necessitam acesso a elas
2. Evitar possíveis *memory leaks*, visto que em um ambiente distribuído milhares de threads podem ser levantadas, e consequentemente se o contexto for propagado a todas elas pode se levar a problemas de performance e carga na aplicação
3. Normalmente a thread volta para um pool após sua utilização, caso as threads mantenham estado/contexto, quando ela for reutilizada você pode acabar utilizando uma informação incorreta na execução do processo

De qualquer forma, quando existe a necessidade de passar informações adiante durante toda a execução de uma thread, pode-se utilizar um [ThreadLocal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) para guardar informações e acessá-las durante o **ciclo de vida da thread em execução**.

O problema é que, threads criadas pela thread em execução não irão ter acesso ao contexto da thread pai, para isso, pode-se utilizar [InheritableThreadLocal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/InheritableThreadLocal.html) para propagar o contexto da thread pai também para as filhas, porém lembre-se, caso milhares de threads compartilhem o contexto, e dependendo do que você colocar neste contexto, você pode acabar tendo problemas.

Outro cuidado que deve-se tomar é sempre limpar o `ThreadLocal` antes/após cada utilização, para se evitar que a thread acesse informações desatualizadas ao buscá-las no holder.

É importante destacar que isso agrega uma complexidade grande ao sistema, visto que você terá que controlar também um ciclo para manter as informações do `ThreadLocal`.

Inclusive existe uma discussão bem interessante nesta [thread do StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14498503/why-should-i-avoid-using-inheritablethreadlocal-in-servlets) sobre a utilização de threads com servlets.